# Binding a Key Vault Certificate with to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-keyvault

I recently acquired an SSL certificate from a provider, and I opted to use a CSR with an Azure Key Vault certificate. Currently, the Key Vault certificate is in an 'Enabled' status, and I have downloaded it in .pem format. Additionally, I have the .crt and .ca-bundle files from the certificate provider.

Now, I'm trying to bind this certificate to an Azure App Service, but I'm encountering some challenges:

- I am unable to use the "Import from Key Vault" source, which I believe is due to limitations with the Access policies on the Key Vault.
- The alternative source is to upload a custom certificate in `.pfx` format. But when clicking `Download in PFX/PEM format`, it always downloads a `.pem` file.

I would appreciate guidance on how to bind the `.pem` certificate to my Azure App Service or any workaround to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

1. Upload the .pem file to a storage account.
2. Create a secret in the key vault using the .pem file.
3. Create a new App Service.
4. In the App Service settings, go to the Certificates tab.
5. Click Add and select From a file.
6. Select the storage account that you uploaded the .pem file to.
7. Select the .pem file and click Add.
8. Click Save.
9. In the App Service settings, go to the Custom domains tab.
10. Click Add and enter the following information:

Domain name: The domain name that you want to bind the certificate to.
SSL type: HTTPS.
Certificate thumbprint: The thumbprint of the certificate that you created in the key vault.

11. Click Save.
12. Test the certificate by navigating to your app service in a browser.

Comment: But, when I choose upload from file, it requires `.pfx` format and choose from local drive (not storage account)